# C - getting incomplete sequence in the debugger

Tags: c

In this project, I get commands from the user and I have to analyze and run them. So this is the part when I actually get the command from the user with `getchar()`:

```
 /* reset variables for the next iteration */
counter = 0, after_command_name = 0, size = 10, tokens_counter = 0;
is_valid_command = true;

/* Getting the command */
command_temp = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
assert(command_temp);
printf("Please enter your command\n");
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ) {
    /* EOF is not allowed */
    if ( c == EOF ) {
        printf("This is not how you should exit this program, please use the \"halt\" function next time.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Check if more memory is needed */
    if (counter == size) {
        if ( (command_temp = realloc(command_temp, ((size *= 10) * sizeof(char)))) == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error trying to allocate more memory.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    command_temp[counter] = (char) c;
    counter++;
}
```

But I don't get the command properly, if I enter some command called `mult_comp_img` like this `mult_comp_img A,     2.5`, 
A is the name of a variable that store a complex number, and the command should take this complex number and multiplies it with the number 2.5, I put a lot of spaces just for testing as the program should take care of extra spaces.
Now with the above code `command_temp` should get the string `mult_comp_img A,     2.5`, but instead this is what I see when I debug the program:

```
command_temp = 0x607250 "mult_com2.5\221", <incomplete sequence \370\001>
```

What's this `\221` and where is A? and "_img"?

I have no idea how to overcome this odd behavior of the program, I also pretty new to C.
Something that may be related to the bug: the above code located inside another loop, that runs as long as the user didn't enter the command `halt` to the console, this is the general structure:

```
int main() {

    int counter, c, size;
    *command_temp;

    for(;;) {

        /* reset variables for the next iteration */
        counter = 0, after_command_name = 0, size = 10, tokens_counter = 0;
        is_valid_command = true;

        /* Getting the command */
        command_temp = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        assert(command_temp);
        printf("Please enter your command\n");
        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' ) {
            /* EOF is not allowed */
            if ( c == EOF ) {
                printf("This is not how you should exit this program, please use the \"halt\" function next time.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            /* Check if more memory is needed */
            if (counter == size) {
                if ( (command_temp = realloc(command_temp, ((size *= 10) * sizeof(char)))) == NULL ) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error trying to allocate more memory.\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            command_temp[counter] = (char) c;
            counter++;
        }

        /*
         * Do stuff here with the command, check it and if everything is ok run a function realted to that
         * command, then return results to the user, and wait to the next command
         * 
         */


    }

    //should I put this here or insinde the loop that runs "forever"?
    free(command_temp);

    return 0;
}
```

This behavior never occurs in the first iteration of the for(;;) loop, so maybe it related somehow to the fact that I override the previous `command_temp` variable without using free before in every iteration?
I'm not sure if I need to free `command_temp` in each iteration or only in the end of the program (as I do now).

Much appreciate your help.

Comment: At `/*
         * Do stuff here with the command, ...*/` command_temp is not yet NUL-terminated.

Comment: You forgot to NUL-terminate your string. Normally you need it only after the last character was read, but if you want to debug-print your string from gdb you have to NUL-terminate it aftrr each character.