# C pointer with recv buffer displaying "Incomplete Sequence"

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

I'm reading some data into a buffer in a recv while loop.

There's content in the front of the buffer that I need to look past and get to the remaining bytes. So I am navigating through the buffer using a pointer to get to the char I want in order to copy the remaining bytes into another buffer.

However, when I look at the pointer position (and the contents that come out of the `strcpy` call), my debugger shows only the first few bytes followed by an "Incomplete Sequence" message, and the buffer copy only includes a few bytes, up to what appears in the buffer to be a byte that reads `\000`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417455/c-getting-incomplete-sequence-in-the-debugger) describes the issue arising from not NUL-terminating the received chars. I did this, and it appears to still be happening. The buffer itself looks fine, but it always appears as if the pointer never is in the correct position.

I am new to C. What is the correct way to get the remaining items so I can do the work necessary to copy out the remaining contents?

```
// reading in 256 bytes and leaving last one open to add null term
// at the start of the loop
// buffer contains: 
//`"[stuff to look past]377\330\377\340\000\020JFIF\000\001\..."`

while ((receivedBytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, MSG_CONFIRM)) > 0) {
               buffer[BUFSIZE] = '\0';
// stuff to do ...
// len is calculated as the length of the start of the buffer to look past
// so move the pointer to the start of the contents I want to copy
// but p = [stuff to look past]377\330\377 <incomplete sequence \340>
// and no content past is read into the pointer
                        char * p = buffer;
                        p += len
// memcpy fails
                        memcpy(content, p, sizeof(content));
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Why is it tagged C++?

Comment: Move the declaration `char * p = buffer;` out of the loop.

Comment: `memcpy(content, p, sizeof(content));` is wrong from inception. `content` must be a pointer (or the first argument type is b.s), which means `sizeof(content)` is the size of a pointer. If that is intended then so be it, but in thirty years I could count on one hand with fingers left over where that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration

```
char * p = `buffer`;
```

Out of the loop (and other suggestions):

```
char * p = NULL;
char content[BUFSIZE];  //this needs to be defined somewhere in your code
                        //as an array if the sizeof macro is to work.
//char *content = calloc(BUFSIZE, 1);//or as a pointer with memory created.
                                     //then freed when no longer needed.


while ((receivedBytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, MSG_CONFIRM)) > 0) {
               buffer[receivedBytes] = '\0';

                        p += receivedBytes;//use receivedBytes to set position.
                        memcpy(content, p, receivedBytes);//use receivedBytes, not sizeof(content). 
                       ...
}
```

There are many references on usage for `recv()`, including these:

*[recv function | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv)*

*[recv() - Unix Linux System Call](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/recv.htm)*

You also mentioned *There's content in the front of the buffer that I need to look past and get to the remaining bytes...*.  Have you considered using either *[strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)*, or *[strchr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm)*.  Both return pointers to either the sub-string searched for, or to the character searched for.

For example, if you have a known unique character that is used as a delimiter in your data string, say '>', then *strchr()* can be used to place the pointer at the content following the location of that `char`:

```
char *p = NULL;
const char source[] = {"this is >test string"};
char buff[20];

p = strchr(source, '>');
if(p)
{

    //     "this is >test string"
    //  p is here   ^
    p++; 
    //     "this is >test string"
    //  p is here    ^  
    strcpy(buff, p);
```

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez - you are welcome.  I am not one of the down voters, but down votes are common when  questions in comments are not answered, or when the example code provided does not meet minimums.  For most questions, if it is possible, a [mcve] should be provided.  Hope this helps.